# how to acces the value of a ForeignKey

Tags: django

How can I multiply a value coming from a FK. Do i need  converting for Decimal again ?
My ideia is multiply the value of FK by field pontos.

> ```
> class Custo(models.Model):
>   valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
>       verbose_name='Valor R$',
>       help_text='Valor do ponto em R$')
>
>   def __unicode__(self):
>       return '%s' % self.valor
>
>
> class Ponto(models.Model):
>   valor = models.ForeignKey(Custo)
>
>   pontos = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
>       help_text='Número de pontos.')
>
>   total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
>       blank=True, null=True,
>       help_text='Preenchido automaticamente.')
>
>
>   def __unicode__(self):
>       return self.bairro
>
> def ponto_pre_save(signal, instance, sender, **kwargs):
>   instance.total = **(instance.valor*instance.pontos**)
> signals.pre_save.connect(ponto_pre_save, sender=Ponto)
> ```

error : unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Custo' and 'Decimal'

Comment: Are you getting an error when you do this? HOw do you know this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the actual field from the foreign key, you were almost there:

```
#                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvv - this is the object (the foreign key)
instance.total = (instance.valor.valor * instance.pontos)
#                                ^^^^^ This is the field you want
```

The error message was also a clue, because its telling you that you are trying to multiple the *instance* `Custo` and not the Decimal value.

In your case both the foreign key name, and the value you want are the same so that's why you have `valor.valor`.